# Remove recursion from sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

A sequence is generated by the following recursion:

$$
A(k) = \frac{1}{1 + {(\beta R)}^{- 1 / \nu} R - {(\beta R)}^{- 1 / \nu} R A(k - 1)}
$$

with $A(0) = 0$. Can you help me with a function that generates $A(k)$ non-recursively? Also, what is $\lim_{k \to \infty} A(k)$?

Comment: Your formula for $A_k$ can be expressed  as $A_k = \frac{1}{f-gA_{k-1}}$. I don't know the condition for its convergence, but if the limit $L$ does exist it should satisfy the similar equation, i.e. $L=\frac{1}{f-gL}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a linear-fractional dynamical system, of the  general form $z^* =  \frac{ az+ b}{cz+d}$. There is a standard trick  in which the numerator and denominator are treated as two components of a vector $(N,D)$ that are updated using $2 \times 2$ matrix notation as $(N^*,D^*)=  (N, D) M$ where $M= \pmatrix{a&c\\b&d   }$ contains $a,b,c,d$.  The iterates of your recursion are therefore matrix powers of $M$ applied to your initial seed value $(N,D)=(0,1)$. You can compute the iterates of matrix $M$ many ways, such as by first finding its eigenvector  basis representation.

Comment: Answer, writing $a=(\beta R)^{-1/\nu}R$: $$A(k) = (1-a^k)/(1-a^{k+1})$$